# Making the size of column headers fixed (MS Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

When I zoom in in Excel, not only the content of the sheet becomes bigger, but also the column headers (A, B, C...). It wouldn't be a problem if I was working on a laptop with a much bigger screen.

Is it possible to make the height of the column headers and the width of row headers fixed? The width of column headers and the height of row headers should change according to the percentage of zooming in/out.

Update
Reply to FaneDuru's comment

This is the default 100% zoom-in:

[image]

200%

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

So the height of the column headers is the same as if it's 100% zoom-in.

P. S. I found out LibreOffice's Calc doesn't change the the height of the column headers while zooming in or out. It would be great if the same were in Excel.

Comment: Do you understand what you are asking, no offence? If you zoom (Out of In) the **column width does not change**! Do you know what column width is? You can test it using `Debug.Print Columns(1).ColumnWidth` before and after Zoom. You only **see** it zoomed/increased. This is the purpose of Zoom in all applications. To see a specific screen area bigger or smaller, of course, neglecting the other neighbor objects, columns, rows etc. How do you imagine a possibility to see **the same headers bigger** and showing **all of them** without **making the screen bigger**?

Comment: @FaneDure, updated the original post. Yeas, when I texted 'size', I meant 'height', sorry

Comment: @FaneDuru, and I was talking about the visual height/width of the column/row headers. Sorry for not being very explicit

Comment: I'm afraid that is exactly the same issue... Even more difficult to find a workaround. If in a cell you can try playing with its width, height size, regarding the standard `headings`, I  do not have the knowledge to be possible to play with their size. But it is possible to hide them: `ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False`...

Answer (score 0):

The possible workaround is to enlarge the font by 'Increase Font Size' and then adjust column width by selecting required columns and double-clicking on the column border in the header row.